# Setting up 3-4 node Cassandra (resource-light) test cluster (s.a. in linux container)?

Tags: cassandra

Trying to see if it is possible to setup a 3 or 4 node Cassandra cluster, with minimum resource requirements, that can be installed on something like a single VM, either inside Linux container, or directly on the single VM using different port-numbers or virtual NICs/IPs.

This will be used for some application demonstration where I might like to demonstrate datastore high-availability, data partitioning, dynamic addition / removal of cluster node.

The setup would be running on a VM running on a laptop, so "resources" are a constraint (i.e. VRAM and VCPUs that can be allocated for this purposes). Also, as the actual data stored would be quite limited (let's say everything in a single key-space, about 10 tables, with 10 odd cols, and 1000 rows).

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like [ccm](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/ccm-a-development-tool-for-creating-local-cassandra-clusters) might be the tool for you. With it, you can create local clusters on your laptop (or in a VM, I suppose), add nodes, delete nodes etc etc. It can be [easily installed](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) on a linux OS, MAC, or [Windows](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/ccm-2-0-and-windows). You don't need to use a VM, your choice. I imagine you would see performance degradation in a VM.